# How to fix this error -"aria-label" attribute accurately describe the element?

Tags: html, css, splunk, wcag

I am trying to fix the aria-label issue in Splunk I have 3 dropdowns. After doing testing using Siteimprove I am facing this issue and also Splunk is not allowing aria-label in the label field

Can anyone suggest how to fix this issue?

```html
<fieldset submitButton="false" autoRun="true"></fieldset>
<row>
  <panel>
    <input type="dropdown" token="area" searchWhenChanged="true">
    <label>Area</label>
    <choice value="*">ALL</choice>
    <fieldForLabel>Area</fieldForLabel>
    <fieldForValue>Area</fieldForValue>
    <search>
      <query>| loadjob savedsearch=Test "Area"</query>
      <done>
        <set token="enabledownload">none</set>
        <unset token="display_details"></unset>
      </done>
    </search>
    <default>*</default>
    <initialValue>*</initialValue>
    </input>
    <input type="dropdown" token="dm" searchWhenChanged="true">
    <label>DM</label>
    <choice value="*">ALL</choice>
    <fieldForLabel>DM/fieldForLabel>
      <fieldForValue>DM</fieldForValue>
      <search>
        <query>| loadjob savedsearch=Test "DM"</query>
      </search>
      <change>
        <set token="enabledownload">none</set>
        <unset token="display_details"></unset>
      </change>
      <default>*</default>
      <initialValue>*</initialValue>
      </input>
      <input type="dropdown" token="al" searchWhenChanged="true">
      <label>AL</label>
      <choice value="*">AL</choice>
      <fieldForLabel>AL</fieldForLabel>
      <fieldForValue>AL</fieldForValue>
      <search>
        <query>| loadjob savedsearch=Test "AL"</query>
      </search>
      <change>
        <set token="enabledownload">none</set>
        <unset token="display_details"></unset>
      </change>
      <default>*</default>
      <initialValue>*</initialValue>
      </input>
      <input type="time" token="date_range" searchWhenChanged="true">
      <label>Date Range</label>
      <default>
        <earliest>-24h@h</earliest>
        <latest>now</latest>
      </default>
      <change>
        <set token="enabledownload">none</set>
        <unset token="display_details"></unset>
      </change>
      </input>
  </panel>
```

Comment: What exactly is the "aria-label" issue?
I'm not familiar with Siteimprove, but you should know that Splunk dashboards are not web sites.
If you wish, you can convert your dashboards into HTML where you will have more flexibility in what you can do with them.  However, Splunk will not edit HTML dashboards so you'll have to update them yourself or keep a copy of your Simple XML dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

What is Siteimproves error message exactly?

If it is concerning the labels to your input fields, I have a solution.

As your code are now, the labels are not connected the input fields.
Whit the label element there are two techniques for doing this, three if you count the aria-label.

Via the for-attribute:

```
<label for="al">AL</label>
<input id="al" type="dropdown" token="al" searchWhenChanged="true">
```

Here its important the value of the for-attribute and the id match.

Embed the input in the label-element

```
<label>AL
<input id="al" type="dropdown" token="al" searchWhenChanged="true">
</label>
```